# IOS How to determine when video clip is finished playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, video

In my application I need to play a movie from vimeo, this goes fine but my hole application is made for portrait only. I want to play the movie in a specific viewController and force this controller to be able to rotate to portrait or landscape.

When someone clicks the thumbnail of the movie, I segue to the VideoViewController, I need to know how to determine when this movie clips is finished so I can segue them back directly after the video is finished.

Code;

```
@implementation VideoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self vimeoVideo];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)vimeoVideo
{
    [YTVimeoExtractor fetchVideoURLFromURL:@"http://vimeo.com/1071123395"
                         quality:YTVimeoVideoQualityMedium
                         referer:@"http://xxxxx.com"
                         completionHandler:^(NSURL *videoURL, NSError *error, YTVimeoVideoQuality quality) {
                             if (error) {
                                 // handle error
                                 NSLog(@"Video URL: %@", [videoURL absoluteString]);
                             } else {
                                 // run player
                                 self.playerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
                                 [self.playerView.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
                                 [self presentViewController:self.playerView animated:YES completion:^(void) {
                                 self.playerView = nil;
                                 }];

                             }
                         }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an observer on viewDidLoad so when your Video will stop playing, let it execute your method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:playerView];
```

This is the receiver method when the video stops playing

```
- (void)moviePlayerDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `MPMoviePlayerController`, there are list of Notifications available for you. The one you need is `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`

```
Posted when a movie has finished playing. The userInfo dictionary of this notification contains the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey key, which indicates the reason that playback finished. This notification is also sent when playback fails because of an error.
```